# Data Saves to MongoDB Database but not views in command

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I use this code to store my data into MongoDB database but it does not view in the database .. and when I use find() to find, it shows my data but not shows when I use db.pick.find() in command. I may be missing something when I setup mongo so please help me.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/pick', { useNewUrlParser: true })
mongoose.connection.once('connected', function(){
console.log("Open Connection")
})
var catSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
age: Number
});

var Cat = mongoose.model("Cat", catSchema);


var newc = new Cat({
name: "cutie",
age: "4"
});

newc.save((err,c) =>{
if(err){
console.log("NewC Err")
}else{
console.log(c)
}
});
```

Comment: "4" is a string btw.

Comment: In mongoose, you can query the data like this: `Cat.findOne(query, callback)`

Comment: @DakshMiglani yes its shows in findOne() but not shows in a command window with db.pick.find()

Comment: seems that pick is the name of your db, not of your collection (cat probably). Try `use pick; db.cat.find()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay atul,

Your database's name is `Pick`, but when you do this query:

`db.pick.findOne({})`, you're technically saying that the database must find a document from the `pick` collection. But looking at the code,  `cat` is the name of your collection.

you can use the `show collections;` command to get the collection names in mongodb and then you can query like this:

> Select the Database

`use pick;`

> get the collection list

`show collections;`

> query the collection

`db.collectionName.findOne({})`